# every closed sphere in metric space is complete, the space is complete

Tags: general-topology

How to show that if every closed sphere in metric space is complete, the space is complete?
can you help me? I need to understand please.

Comment: Do you mean closed space not sphere right ?

Comment: Or do you mean closed ball? Following Brian Scott’s answer, closed balls being complete should suffice. I don’t know about closed spheres.

Comment: @subrosar. It should be closed ball. A sphere should be $\{x: d(x,c)=r\}$ for some $c,r.$ In $\Bbb Q$ a "sphere" has just 0,1,or 2 members so it's complete, but $\Bbb Q$ is not complete.

Answer (score 4):

HINT: You should know that every closed subset of a complete metric space is complete; that result establishes one direction of the theorem. For the other direction observe that every Cauchy sequence is bounded, so it lies completely inside … what?

Comment: @Brain M. Scott. Do you have chance to see my of the restriction two hours ago? If not try to see it I think is correct but I need to make sure